# Stop generating javax.annotation source files in Android APK

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit, javax

I am using retrofit library and while generating the APK the apk contains java source files under **javax.annotations** in the APK.

I tried using **proguard** and **minifyEnabled**, Still the java source files persist in the extracted APK.

Is there any way to disable generating the java source files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with react-native dependency.

If we want to avoid those files getting in to APK, then we can **exclude** those files. In my case I did

```
packagingOptions {
        exclude 'javax/annotation/*'
        exclude 'javax/annotation/meta/*'
        exclude 'javax/annotation/concurrent/*'
    }
```